# Change rabbitmq exchange with nestjs

Tags: rabbitmq, nestjs

I am using rabbitmq with nestjs. I need to replicate a message from one queue to another. I set up an exchange on rabbitmq to make it work. But how can I change the exchange of rabbitmq inside nestjs?

my api gateway

my current rabbitmq configuration inside nestjs:

```
constructor( ) {
    this.rabbitmq = ClientProxyFactory.create({
      transport: Transport.RMQ,
      options: {
        urls: [`amqp://${this.configService.get<string>('RABBITMQ_USER')}:${this.configService.get<string>('RABBITMQ_PASSWORD')}@${this.configService.get<string>('RABBITMQ_URL')}`],
        queue: 'students'
      }
    })
  }

  createStudent(@Body() body: CreateStudentDto): Observable<any> {
    return this.rabbitmq.send('createStudent', body)
  }
```

my client

```
@MessagePattern('createStudent')
    async createStudent(@Payload() student: Student, @Ctx() context: RmqContext) {

        const channel = context.getChannelRef()
        const originalMsg = context.getMessage()
        try {
            let response = await this.studentService.createStudent(student)
            await channel.ack(originalMsg)
            return response;
        } catch(error) {

            this.logger.log(`error: ${JSON.stringify(error.message)}`)
            const filterAckError = ackErrors.filter(ackError => error.message.includes(ackError))

            if (filterAckError.length > 0) {
                await channel.ack(originalMsg)
            }
        }
    }
```

I need the message to be sent to two queues.

Comment: hi, did you figure out the required configuration?

Comment: nestjs does not allow it. It is limited. I decided to install this library.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nestjs-plus/rabbitmq

Comment: this might be a better option as it seems to have better support and recent updates.... 

https://github.com/golevelup/nestjs/tree/master/packages/rabbitmq